# Calculating the size of an Axis Aligned Bounding Box

Tags: collision-detection, lwjgl, aabb

I am currently following ThinMatrix's 3d game development tutorial using LWJGL and OpenGL. I am trying to implement collision detection in my game. I have got the code ready to detect AABB vs AABB collisions but can't seem to figure out how to get the size of the bounding boxes around the entities. Can someone guide me to calculate the size of the AABB? This is the OBJFileLoader class -

```
package objConverter;

import models.RawModel;
import org.lwjgl.util.vector.*;
import renderEngine.Loader;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class OBJFileLoader {
    private static final String RES_LOC = "res/models/";

    public static RawModel loadOBJ(String objFileName, Loader loader) {
        FileReader isr = null;
        File objFile = new File(RES_LOC + objFileName + ".obj");
        try {
            isr = new FileReader(objFile);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.err.println("File not found in res; don't use any extension: " + e.getMessage());
        }
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(isr);
        String line;
        List<Vertex> vertices = new ArrayList<>();
        List<Vector2f> textures = new ArrayList<>();
        List<Vector3f> normals = new ArrayList<>();
        List<Integer> indices = new ArrayList<>();
        try {
            while (true) {
                line = reader.readLine();
                if (line.startsWith("v ")) {
                    String[] currentLine = line.split(" ");
                    Vector3f vertex = new Vector3f(Float.valueOf(currentLine[1]), Float.valueOf(currentLine[2]), Float.valueOf(currentLine[3]));
                    Vertex newVertex = new Vertex(vertices.size(), vertex);
                    vertices.add(newVertex);
                } else if (line.startsWith("vt ")) {
                    String[] currentLine = line.split(" ");
                    Vector2f texture = new Vector2f(Float.valueOf(currentLine[1]), Float.valueOf(currentLine[2]));
                    textures.add(texture);
                } else if (line.startsWith("vn ")) {
                    String[] currentLine = line.split(" ");
                    Vector3f normal = new Vector3f(Float.valueOf(currentLine[1]), Float.valueOf(currentLine[2]), Float.valueOf(currentLine[3]));
                    normals.add(normal);
                } else if (line.startsWith("f ")) {
                    break;
                }
            }
            while (line != null && line.startsWith("f ")) {
                String[] currentLine = line.split(" ");
                String[] vertex1 = currentLine[1].split("/");
                String[] vertex2 = currentLine[2].split("/");
                String[] vertex3 = currentLine[3].split("/");
                Vertex v0 = processVertex(vertex1, vertices, indices);
                Vertex v1 = processVertex(vertex2, vertices, indices);
                Vertex v2 = processVertex(vertex3, vertices, indices);
                calculateTangents(v0, v1, v2, textures);
                line = reader.readLine();
            }
            reader.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("Error reading the file");
        }
        removeUnusedVertices(vertices);
        float[] verticesArray = new float[vertices.size() * 3];
        float[] texturesArray = new float[vertices.size() * 2];
        float[] normalsArray = new float[vertices.size() * 3];
        float[] tangentsArray = new float[vertices.size() * 3];
        float furthest = convertDataToArrays(vertices, textures, normals, verticesArray, texturesArray, normalsArray, tangentsArray);
        int[] indicesArray = convertIndicesListToArray(indices);
        //        ModelData data = new ModelData(verticesArray, texturesArray, normalsArray, tangentsArray, indicesArray, furthest);
        return loader.loadToVAO(verticesArray, texturesArray, normalsArray, indicesArray);
    }

    private static void calculateTangents(Vertex v0, Vertex v1, Vertex v2, List<Vector2f> textures) {
        Vector3f delatPos1 = Vector3f.sub(v1.getPosition(), v0.getPosition(), null);
        Vector3f delatPos2 = Vector3f.sub(v2.getPosition(), v0.getPosition(), null);
        Vector2f uv0 = textures.get(v0.getTextureIndex());
        Vector2f uv1 = textures.get(v1.getTextureIndex());
        Vector2f uv2 = textures.get(v2.getTextureIndex());
        Vector2f deltaUv1 = Vector2f.sub(uv1, uv0, null);
        Vector2f deltaUv2 = Vector2f.sub(uv2, uv0, null);

        float r = 1.0f / (deltaUv1.x * deltaUv2.y - deltaUv1.y * deltaUv2.x);
        delatPos1.scale(deltaUv2.y);
        delatPos2.scale(deltaUv1.y);
        Vector3f tangent = Vector3f.sub(delatPos1, delatPos2, null);
        tangent.scale(r);
        v0.addTangent(tangent);
        v1.addTangent(tangent);
        v2.addTangent(tangent);
    }

    private static Vertex processVertex(String[] vertex, List<Vertex> vertices, List<Integer> indices) {
        int index = Integer.parseInt(vertex[0]) - 1;
        Vertex currentVertex = vertices.get(index);
        int textureIndex = Integer.parseInt(vertex[1]) - 1;
        int normalIndex = Integer.parseInt(vertex[2]) - 1;
        if (!currentVertex.isSet()) {
            currentVertex.setTextureIndex(textureIndex);
            currentVertex.setNormalIndex(normalIndex);
            indices.add(index);
            return currentVertex;
        } else {
            return dealWithAlreadyProcessedVertex(currentVertex, textureIndex, normalIndex, indices, vertices);
        }
    }

    private static int[] convertIndicesListToArray(List<Integer> indices) {
        int[] indicesArray = new int[indices.size()];
        for (int i = 0; i < indicesArray.length; i++) {
            indicesArray[i] = indices.get(i);
        }
        return indicesArray;
    }

    private static float convertDataToArrays(List<Vertex> vertices, List<Vector2f> textures, List<Vector3f> normals, float[] verticesArray, float[] texturesArray, float[] normalsArray, float[] tangentsArray) {
        float furthestPoint = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < vertices.size(); i++) {
            Vertex currentVertex = vertices.get(i);
            if (currentVertex.getLength() > furthestPoint) {
                furthestPoint = currentVertex.getLength();
            }
            Vector3f position = currentVertex.getPosition();
            Vector2f textureCoord = textures.get(currentVertex.getTextureIndex());
            Vector3f normalVector = normals.get(currentVertex.getNormalIndex());
            Vector3f tangent = currentVertex.getAverageTangent();
            verticesArray[i * 3] = position.x;
            verticesArray[i * 3 + 1] = position.y;
            verticesArray[i * 3 + 2] = position.z;
            texturesArray[i * 2] = textureCoord.x;
            texturesArray[i * 2 + 1] = 1 - textureCoord.y;
            normalsArray[i * 3] = normalVector.x;
            normalsArray[i * 3 + 1] = normalVector.y;
            normalsArray[i * 3 + 2] = normalVector.z;
            tangentsArray[i * 3] = tangent.x;
            tangentsArray[i * 3 + 1] = tangent.y;
            tangentsArray[i * 3 + 2] = tangent.z;
        }
        return furthestPoint;
    }

    private static Vertex dealWithAlreadyProcessedVertex(Vertex previousVertex, int newTextureIndex, int newNormalIndex, List<Integer> indices, List<Vertex> vertices) {
        if (previousVertex.hasSameTextureAndNormal(newTextureIndex, newNormalIndex)) {
            indices.add(previousVertex.getIndex());
            return previousVertex;
        } else {
            Vertex anotherVertex = previousVertex.getDuplicateVertex();
            if (anotherVertex != null) {
                return dealWithAlreadyProcessedVertex(anotherVertex, newTextureIndex, newNormalIndex, indices, vertices);
            } else {
                Vertex duplicateVertex = new Vertex(vertices.size(), previousVertex.getPosition());
                duplicateVertex.setTextureIndex(newTextureIndex);
                duplicateVertex.setNormalIndex(newNormalIndex);
                previousVertex.setDuplicateVertex(duplicateVertex);
                vertices.add(duplicateVertex);
                indices.add(duplicateVertex.getIndex());
                return duplicateVertex;
            }
        }
    }

    private static void removeUnusedVertices(List<Vertex> vertices) {
        for (Vertex vertex : vertices) {
            vertex.averageTangents();
            if (!vertex.isSet()) {
                vertex.setTextureIndex(0);
                vertex.setNormalIndex(0);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Just find the minimum and maximum position along each axis of that mesh's vertices.

Comment: Sorry, but can you show an example of that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I followed this tutorial a long while back.  What you need to do is store minimum and maximum x, y, and z components.  I would recommend doing this in the case in which you are storing vertices.  You could do something like this:

```
float minX, minY, minZ, maxX, maxY, maxZ;

try {
    while(true) {
        if ("v ") {
            Vector3f ver = new Vector3f(Float.valueOf(curentLine[0]... );
            if (ver.x < minX) minX = ver.x;
            else if (ver.x > maxX) maxX = ver.x;
            if (ver.y < minY) minY = ver.y;
            ...
        }
    ...
}
```

This is a crude, but easy way to go about getting the minimum and maximum x, y, and z bounds of an entity.  Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

The sheer size of an aabb should be `max - min`; all max components minus negative. Max - min is also known as the diagonal (an aabb is by itself diagonal).

Here is an example that uses glm:

```
vec3 max(100);
vec3 min(90);

vec3 size = max - min; // vec3(10)
```