# Axis-Aligned Bounding Box Calculation (AABB) for different orientations of 3D object

Tags: computer-vision, bounding-box, cad

I am trying to calculate the Axis-Aligned Bounding Box of a 3d CAD model (.stp file) for different orientations.

More specifically, imagine a 3d object lying on a virtual workbench and we have a top view of it in a CAD program.
We only care about the top view (representing the projection of the object on the XY plane).
The final goal is to create a table containing the ratio of the bounding box X and Y sides for every degree of rotation.
Τhe following sketches clarify what I mean.
Any ideas/ suggestions for any part of the task?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I've got two ideas for solution approaches. (depending of the capability of your cad software)

1. Using kind of "extreme point" function. Get the coordinates of these extreme points by varying the direction the point is generated
2. Create a straight line (or plane in 3d) which does not intersect your geometry. Measure the minimal distance between your body an the line/plane. Rotate the line/plane around your body (around the cog) stepwise to get multiple measurements.

Comment: This could work but sounds a bit complicated.
I discovered the term "axis aligned bounding box" which is what I need to calculate as well as a an implementation here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43493347/calculating-the-size-of-an-axis-aligned-bounding-box

What remains to be done is to try it myself.